# How do you parse a difficult .txt file?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm fairly new to java and have been attempting to read a very difficult .txt file and input it into my MySQL DB.

To me, the file has some very weird delimiting rules. the delimiting seems to be all commas but other parts just do not make any sense. here is a few examples:

```
" "," "," "," "," "

" ",,,,,,," "

" ",0.00," "

" ",," ",," ",," "
```

What I do know is that all fields containing letters will be the normal `,"text",` format.

all columns that only have numerals will follow this format: `,0.00,` except for the first column which follows the normal format `"123456789",`

Then anything with no data will alternate between `,,` or `," ",`

I have been able to get the program to read correctly with java.sql.Statement but I need it to work with java.sql.PreparedStatement

I can get it to work with only a few columns selected but I need this to work with 100+ columns and some fields contain commas e.g. `"Some Company, LLC"`

Here is the code I currently have but I am at a loss as to where to go next.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.*;


public class AccountTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        //Declare DB settings
    String dbName = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/local";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";
    String fileName = "file.txt";
    String psQuery = "insert into accounttest"
                     + "(account,account_name,address_1,address_2,address_3) values"
                     + "(?,?,?,?,?)";
    Connection connect = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    String account = null;
    String accountName = null;
    String address1 = null;
    String address2 =null;
    String address3 = null;


        //Load JDBC Driver
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("JDBC driver not found.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }


        //Attempt connection
    try {
    connect = DriverManager.getConnection(dbName,userName,password);
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("E1: Connection Failed.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;         
    }


        //Verify connection
    if (connect != null) {
        System.out.println("Connection successful.");
    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("E2: Connection Failed.");
    }


      BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        String line;

        //import file into mysql DB
    try {

        //Looping the read block until all lines in the file are read.
    while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {

            //Splitting the content of comma delimited file
        String data[] = line.split("\",\"");

            //Renaming array items for ease of use
        account = data[0];
        accountName = data[1];
        address1 = data[2];
        address2 = data[3];
        address3 = data[4];

            // removing double quotes so they do not get put into the db
        account = account.replaceAll("\"", "");
        accountName = accountName.replaceAll("\"", "");
        address1 = address1.replaceAll("\"", "");
        address2 = address2.replaceAll("\"", "");
        address3 = address3.replaceAll("\"", "");

            //putting data into database
        statement = connect.prepareStatement(psQuery);
        statement.setString(1, account);
        statement.setString(2, accountName);
        statement.setString(3, address1);
        statement.setString(4, address2);
        statement.setString(5, address3);
        statement.executeUpdate();
    }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        statement = null;
    }
    finally {
        bReader.close();
    }
}   
}
```

Sorry if it's not formatted correctly, I am still learning and after being flustered for several days trying to figure this out, I didn't bother making it look nice.

My question is would something like this be possible with such a jumbled up file? if so, how do I go about making this a possibility? Also, I am not entirely familiar with prepared statements, do I have to declare every single column or is there a simpler way?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT :** To clarify what I need is I need to upload a txt file to a MySQL database, I need a way to read and split(unless there is a better way) the data based on either `","`, `,,,,`, `,0.00,` and still keep fields together that have commas in the field `Some Company, LLC`. I need to do this with 100+ columns and the file varies from 3000 to 6000 rows. Doing this as a prepared statement is required. I'm not sure if this is possible but I appreciate any input anyone might have on the matter.

**EDIT2 :** I was able to figure out how to get the messy file sorted out thanks to rpc1. instead of `String data[] = line.split("\",\"");` I used `String data[] = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");` I still had to write out each variable to link it to the `data[]` then write out each `statement.setString` for each column as well as write the `replaceALL("\"", "");` for each column but I got it working and I couldn't find another way to use prepared statements. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: The way on how you're using PreparedStatement seems pretty good to me. You even use `executeUpdate()` which is right while many begginers use `executeQuery()` on INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements which isn't. About the file if it hasn't a well defined format then it would be very difficult (or even impossible) work with it.

Comment: Thanks. I spent two days reading stackoverflow questions and kind of realized what is and isn't good practice. I know that this works with the regular statement with the query defining the how the file is delimited. I don't understand how it was able to read it correctly but it did.

Comment: Don't you get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you process the 3rd line of your file? It should be splitted in a 3-length array and calling `data[3]` should throw an exception.

Comment: I don't see why you need to manually parse the csv file, you can use a 3rd party csv parser like JavaCSV. And please don't respond with my boss / lecturer told me so

Comment: It's not a csv file and the server cannot be altered to add a third party application. Company policy. I may run the server but I don't have say as to what can be added on which is why I have to do it the hard way.

Comment: dic19, I'm not sure what you are meaning. there are 5 columns so the maximum of the array is `data[4]` If I were to call `data[5]` I would get an out of bounds exception.

Comment: I mean the 3rd line is `" ",0.00," "`, right? Then when you split this line `data` array won't have 5 elements. Am I right? @Ak_Crusader

Comment: No, those examples are just parts of the file. the five columns I was working with only are delimited by `","` sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The fields without anything in between commas should have null values.  When there's only whitespace in the string, just treat it as a normal string.  If you can't use third-party libraries, you're screwed - you're going to have to re-invent so much stuff; sane date/time handling (until Java 8), handy utility functions, etc.  Granted you can't just put stuff on at a whim (licenses. after all), but there are a number of solutions that can help with that (setting up a local mirror of a Maven repository which limits to approved licenses, etc).

Comment: This question is about how to parse the text file. It doesn't have anything to do with `PreparedStatement` really.

Comment: It consisted of two questions. how to parse the text file correctly with PreparedStatement and how to make it dynamic. Both are answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out both issues that I was having by this little bit of code. Again, thanks for all of your help!

```
for (String line = bReader.readLine(); line != null; line = bReader.readLine()) {   

          //Splitting the content of comma delimited file
    String data[] = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

         //Iterating through the file and updating the table.
    statement = connect.prepareStatement(psQuery);
    for (int i =0; i < data.length;i++) {
        temp =  data[i];
        temp = temp.replaceAll("\"", "");
        statement.setString(i+1, temp);
    }
    statement.executeUpdate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cycles
for  example:

```
    String psQuery = "insert into accounttest"
                         + "(account,account_name,address_1,address_2,address_3,..,adrress_n) values"
                         + "(?,?,?,?,?,?,..,?)";  //you have to put m=n+2 values

.....

     //you can change separator 
            String data[] = line.replace("\",\"",";").replace("\"","").split(";");

              for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
              { 
                  if(i<data.length) //if index smaller then array siz
                      statement.setString(i+1, data[i]);
                  else
                      statement.setString(i+1, ""); //put null
              }
              statement.executeUpdate();
```

P.S. if your csv file large use batch insert  (addBatch()) 
and use Pattern  to split string

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(";",""); 
p.split(st);
```

**EDIT**
Try this split function

```
private static Pattern pSplit = Pattern.compile("[^,\"']+|\"([^\"]*)\"|'([^']*)'"); //set pattern as global var
private static Pattern pReplace = Pattern.compile("\"");
public static Object[] split(String st)
{
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   Matcher m = pSplit.matcher(st);
   while (m.find())
   list.add( pReplace.matcher(m.group(0)).replaceAll("")); // Add .replace("\"", "") to remove surrounding quotes.
   return list.toArray();
}
```

for example
intput string: `st="\"1212\",\"LL C ,DDD \",\"CA, SPRINGFIELD\",232.11,3232.00";`
split on 5 item array:

```
1212
LL C ,DDD
CA, SPRINGFIELD
232.11
3232.00
```

**EDIT2**

```
this example solves all your problems (even empty values)


private static Pattern pSplit = Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
public static String[] split2(String st)
{
    String[] tokens = pSplit.split(st);       
    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't word it correctly. This is a good bit of code that I will remember for later. What I currently need is to figure out a way to split the file correctly, depending on how that part of the file is being delimited. So if it comes across `","` it can split from that but also split from `,0.00,` as well as delimit from `,,,,` I don't know if this is a possibility with prepared statements.

Comment: Oo, I've got your problem...
And have one question:
Is number of fields in each row constant?
If yes, I have a idea how to solve your problem

Comment: yes, the number are fields are constant, just the way it gets to that number is awkward and different for each row. I would love to hear what you have.

Comment: but there is problem with empty data, you can edit pattern by yourself to solve this problem, or  replace empty values
for example replace(",,",",\"\","

Comment: Might take me a bit to figure this out. My IDE is giving me weird errors with this like:  `Syntax error on token "(", ; expected Syntax error on token ")", ; expected` on `split2(String st)` Thanks for your reply, I will work on getting this implemented and see if this is the fix.

Comment: try to define global variable
   private static Pattern pSplit;
but initialize it in "main" procedure
   pSplit=Pattern.compile(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

Comment: I couldn't get your code to work for me for some strange reason. but you did give me an idea that worked. I have edited my post to reflect so.